# My makeshift calculator isn't able to access the library I made, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, function

In python I have a library that I made that contains makeshift functions for a calculator as a learning project. It worked earlier but now the main program can't get definitions of functions or variables from the library.

Main executable:

````
```print('Version 1.2.1 Beta')
print('Notice: Version 1.1.3 is unstable')
import maths
run = True
while run == True:
    print getFunction
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    desFunction = inLine
    checkFunction()
````

Library:

```
    #Mathematical Symposium
#Begin Assignments
print('Version 1.1.4')
print('Converted to pylib for math functions')
print('Non-Executable')
print('Alternatively you can define desFunction as your function then execute checkFunction()')
getFunction = 'Please input desired function'
getX = 'Please input the first numerical value'
getY = 'Please input the second numerical value'
ans = 'Null'
run = True
#End Assignments
#Begin Definitions
def funcdir():
    functionli = ['add', 'subtract', 'multiply', 'divide', 'square root']
    print functionli
def checkFunction():
    if desFunction == 'add':
        add()
    elif desFunction == 'subtract':
        subtract()
    elif desFunction == 'multiply':
        multiply()
    elif desFunction == 'divide':
        divide()
    elif desFunction == 'square root':
        sqroot()
    elif desFunction == 'halt':
        run = False
    elif desFunction == 'help':
        funcdir()
def add():
    print getX
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    x = inLine
    print getY
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    y = inLine
    ans = float(x) + float(y)
    print ans
def subtract():
    print getX
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    x = inLine
    print getY
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    y = inLine
    ans = float(x) - float(y)
    print ans
def multiply():
    print getX
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    x = inLine
    print getY
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    y = inLine
    ans = float(x) * float(y)
    print ans
def divide():
    print getX
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    x = inLine
    print getY
    inLine = raw_input('>>> ')
    y = inLine
    ans = float(x) / float(y)
    print ans
def sqroot():
    import math
    num = input('>>> ')
    print math.sqrt(num)
#End Definitions
#Begin Visible Process
#No Visible Process
#End Visible Process
```

If anyone knows how to fix this, it would be a big help. Thanks.

Comment: If you were using an editor with a built in shell to test your library, it may have still been loaded into memory when you tested the first time. After you restarted the shell and ran your main program the functions from the library were no longer in the global namespace, but instead in the `maths` namespace, requiring you to call `maths.add`, `maths.subtract`, etc...

Comment: Thanks - that makes a lot of sense - and that part slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

After you import "maths", it's functions and variables are accessible as "maths.getFunction", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Importing a module only adds the *name* of the module to the current namespace. It doesn't give you direct access to the module's contents. For that you need to either use attribute access syntax (`print maths.getFunction` for instance), or use `from module import names` to explicitly import some names (either listing all the names you want, or using `*` to import everything). You may want `from maths import getFunction, checkFunction` (though I'm not sure what your `desFunction` line is supposed to do).